# Realtek PCIE ethernet adapter missing

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers, lan

Good day!

I was downloading a program from the internet when my pc suddenly crashed  and upon pc restart, I noticed that my LAN connection went missing. Upon inspection in my Device Manager, I noticed that my LAN adapter completely vanished. I tried to scan for any hardware changes to somehow resolved the issue but nothing happened. I tried installing the LAN driver of my pc but kept on receiving "Deep Sleep" error. I have tried resetting my BIOS to default based on the searches I found but still the error persist.

I installed a program called "Driver Easy" on my pc to identify whether I still have the LAN driver. To my surprise, no issues were found in my LAN driver. I looked at my LAN port and noticed that it is not blinking. Just showing a steady orange color.

My PC is already three years old and it is running on a AMD A4-6300 processor. Should I reformat my PC for my LAN to return or is there any solution to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably defective. However, regardless of the BIOS (actually UEFI) defaults please do check whether or not it is disabled, as it could be as simple as that (and resetting to default not always enable previously disabled onboard devices). If it's enabled then you may try to reinstall the OS - better try with a live Linux session, Ubuntu should be fine - but it's likely to be a waste of time.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The UEFI is enabled. Still error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [live cd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) would be good to see if there is a driver/OS issue. If that doesn't work, I would suggest a PCI or PCI express network card (A quick look shows they are around £10 on Amazon). Fit the card when the PC is off, boot your machine (it should install automatically) and then use the new network port.

Comment: Ok sir. I would try this. Thanks